# Representing a number in r0 + r1 E + r2 E^2 form

Tags: numerics, linear-algebra, number-theory, number-representation, approximation

Let `E` be the base of natural logarithm `2.71...`

A Sequence `S[n]` is believed to converge to a real number `L`, such that `L` is of a form of

```
L = r0 + r1 E + r2 E^2
```

where `r0,r1,r2` are rational numbers of small enumerator and denominator.

The sequence seems to converge quickly, so `S[1000]` and `S[10000]` are almost the same.

So I am trying to find `r0,r1,r2` such that

`S[10000] ≒ r0 + r1 E + r2 E^2`

Is there any related built-in feature in MMA ?

Comment: Can you explain what you are looking for? For example, what's wrong with the solution r0 = s[10000], r1=0, r2=0?

Answer (score 3):

```
{r2, r1, r0} = FoldPairList[QuotientRemainder, 10000, {E^2, E^1, E^0}]
```

> {1353, 0, 2}

```
{r2, r1, r0} . {E^2, E^1, E^0} // Total // N
```

> 9999.39